# how to get authentication provider status list from IIS. For share point site?

Tags: sharepoint, iis, authentication, provider

I need to get the authentication provider status of i web application available in IIS?.

Ex:

Is Basic Authentication available for X site?.
through c# or python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use code like this:

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("site_url_here"))
    {
      var webApp = site.WebApplication;
      var customZoneSettings = webApp.IisSettings[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUrlZone.Custom];
      bool useBasicForCustomZone = customZoneSettings.UseBasicAuthentication;
    }
```

Here you get parent SPWebApplication for specified site and looking for its IisSettings for specified zone (because there could be different settings for different zones). SPIisSettings object contains a lot of properties which will help to complete your task, for example, UseBasicAuthentication.

Comment: is that possible to do with java script or through web services??

Comment: sure, you need to write a webservice which will work on Sharepoint server (for example, in Layouts folder) and will work with Sharepoint Object Model (like code above). Then you can call this web service method (bool IsSiteSupportsBasicAuth(string siteUrl)) directly or from JavaScript and get the result.